# How to find the system date of image stored in android phone?

Tags: android, image, datetime

I want to get the system's date and time for the image stored on the android phone and not the image's date and time. Can it be possible to retrieve the system's date and time of when the image was stored on the phone?

Ex: I add an image taken on june 2007 in my phone today then can i get today's detail of the image i.e today's date and time stored of the image.?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the file creation date. Android does not allow you to retrieve this, but you can get the last modified date from the `File` object:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Date lastModifiedDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("Last Modified Date : "+ lastModifiedDate.toString());
```

Keep in mind that if the user edits the file, it will change to the date of the edit, not the date of creation.

Comment: but here i will get the date only if the user modifies the file if he does not modify it will not give me any date right?>

Comment: @android_developer If it is not modified, it should return the creation date.